# Does a Maximal Planar graph have Euler cycle

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

I was given today in the text the following information:
G is a maximal planar graph over $n>2$ vertices.
given that $\chi(G)=3$, prove there is an Euler Cycle in the graph.

Now, I believe this isn't correct for $n>3$.

Because for every Vertex you add to the graph, you add exactly three edges. So the graph  must have one vertex with an odd degree therefore there wont be an Euler cycle.

I need help in telling if im correct or otherwise what is the proof for this statement.

Comment: The result is true and is in fact an if and only if, a maximal lanar graph (also called triangulation) is euelerian if and only if its chromatic number is $3$.

Comment: The information in the first line is correct. 
What does the neighborhood of a vertex in a maximal planar graph look like? Can you use this information to show that if $\chi(G) = 3$, then every vertex of the graph must have even degree?

Comment: @Yorch So im incorrect? How can a graph be maximal and planar and have a chromatic number of 3? I tried drawing it for n=4,5,6 and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument shows that no eulerian triangulation can be obtained by adding a vertex inside a face in a preixisting triangulation and splitting that face into the 3 triangles with the new vertex.

This does not show that no eulerian triangulations exist, for an example of such a graph consider the octahedron.

The theorem is true and is in fact an if and only if, although you are only asked to prove the easy direction.

If there was a vertex of odd degree you can consider the faces around that vertex, and since it's a triangulation you get a cycle of odd length around that vertex, hence not $3$-colorable.

Comment: Unfortunately im not able to see how its true. If i add a vertex to a maximal planar graph, to keep it maximal the vertex would have 3 edges and therefore no euler cycle, no?

Comment: if you had a vertex of odd degree $v$ then its neighbours are all connected between each other and form a cycle (because the triangles go around $v$ ). And if you have a vertex that is neighbour to everything in an odd cycle then you need at least $4$ colors.

Comment: @Aaron yeah you are correct ! But that construction doesn't cover all of the graphs, consider the graph of the octahedron, it can't be obtained that way. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Octahedron_graph.png

Comment: there is a graph wherr it works, but it doesnt apply to all graphs, under these assumptions, right? So if the chromatic number is 3, G might not have an Euler cycle, right?

Comment: If $G$ is a triangulation and $G$ has chromatic number $3$ then every vertex has even degree, and therefore has an euler cycle. The proof I give is by contrapositive , and is in the last paragraph of my post.